Using a custom role provider in .NET 8 with no scaffolding and custom database
It used to be with older .NET versions that you could use forms authentication along with a custom role provider to handle role checking. With this, I could use [Authorize(Roles="xxx,yyy,zzz")] to check roles on a controller or action method, and IsInRole("role") in Razor pages to check a role.
With ASP.NET Core 8 MVC web applications, it seems the implementation changed dramatically from the previous versions and despite my best efforts, I can't find a way to achieve this anymore.
Given I'm using forms authentication and handling all of the user authentication myself, how can I create a custom role provider that still works with [Authorize(Roles="xxx,yyy,zzz")] on controllers and action methods (note - multiple roles checked on one line), and IsInRole("xxx") in the Razor view, using purely my own table layout shown below. I don't want to use code first database generation, or any of the scaffolded database tables.
Many thanks!



User


Role


UserRole





UserId
guid

RoleId
guid

UserId
guid


Email
nvarchar(250)

Title
nvarchar(50)

RoleId
guid




Finally got to the bottom of this.  For anyone else who is struggling, the key is to add claims for each role for the user who's successfully authenticated. Once you add these role claims, the roles in both Authorize[] and IsInRole() work fine.  My authentication controller ended up looking like this:
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Check your user credentials here and return a user object
    // with associated role names
    var ReturnedUser = await CheckYourUserHere(model.Email, model.Password);

    // If login was good
    if (ReturnedUser != null)
    {
        // Build standard claims
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new(ClaimTypes.Name, ReturnedUser.FirstName),
            new(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, ReturnedUser.Id.ToString())
        };

        // Add role names as individual claims
        foreach (var role in ReturnedUser.UserRoles)
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Role.Title));

        // Make claims identity
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        // Build authentication properties
        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = model.RememberMe
        };

        // Sign in
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);

        // Redirect
        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl ?? "/Home");
    }
    else 
    { 
        TempData["errormessage"] = StatusMessage;
    }
}

return View(model);

You should now be able to use Authorize attribute with multiple roles and IsInRole() should still work.
